# onActivityResult does not execute when intent has Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Tags: android, android-activity

**A.java**

```
public class A extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(A.class.getName(), "OnCreate");

        Intent intentB = new Intent(this, B.class);
        intentB.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intentB);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(A.class.getName(), "onActivityResult");
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(B.class.getName(), "OnCreate");

        Intent imagesIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        imagesIntent.setType("image/*");
        Intent openGalleryIntent = Intent.createChooser(imagesIntent, "pic");
        startActivityForResult(openGalleryIntent, 2);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(B.class.getName(), "onActivityResult");
        Log.d(B.class.getName(), data.getData().toString());
    }

}
```

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".A"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="B"></activity>

    </application>
```

The **problem** is after selecting image from gallery, onActivityResult() method of class B class does not execute.

Though if `intentB.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)` is removed from intentB instance then onActivityResult() of class B executes fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. When you select FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY as the flag while calling the next activity. The child activity is removed from the stack and hence once you move out it would simply finish.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

The question is why do you even want to use that flag?

Comment: I do not want to show that activity again when user hits Back button. Actually, I misunderstood the fundamental concepts. Anyway, I got hint from your answer.